# Transfer folder from MacBook to iPad

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, airdrop

I want to transfer folder that contains many video files from MacBook to iPad. I don't want to use iCloud. I use AirDrop. Is there any 3rd party App, or how can I easily transfer and see the files in the folder in iPad?

Comment: If you can tell us what apps you've already tried (after searching the App Store) and why they didn't work for you, it will prevent us from providing unnecessary answers.  See [this post for how to ask for software recommendations](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation).

Comment: I did not use any APP, I transferred a few video files individually, and found that they were in Photo and Videos.

Comment: What file type in that folder? Try using ifunbox or 3U tools

Comment: Video and audio files

Comment: @Mithun, what is the ideal situation? Is the problem in the transfer process being too complicated or are you having issues putting the files in the right places? Are you trying to transfer the files for storage or do you want to view them on the device? One thought I had about the video files at the very least, was [Plex Media Server](https://www.plex.tv/), which is a pretty simple way to stream files to your mobile devices (for instance) from a pc or mac. Maybe that's too complicated. I didn't really get a good understanding of how you wish this all would go down.

Comment: @Joonas I want to transfer video file from Mac to iPad. I don't want to use iCloud or iTunes. Obviously, I want to view them on my iPad, and play them offline using some kind of video player. Generally, I use GOM media player. However, I am flexible to use any media player. The problem is that when I use airdrop, after transfer, I could not able to find on iPad. I want transfer -> view them in right place -> play them offline.

Comment: @Mithun, I think your best bet may be  [VLC player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html) or some similar player. It does have a Web GUI for transferring files over local network, but these always tend to fail if you try to push like over 10 files at the same time. No matter what app it is, in my experience. VLC player also can connect to cloud services like Google drive and Dropbox and download or stream files from them, although they are not ideal for multiple files either.

Comment: @Joonas somehow it's working. But, the transfer speed is very slow.

Comment: @Mithun, I have no idea why it would be. I've been able to transfer files pretty fast with it. The only "solution" I can think of is transferring the files through itunes to the vlc player app.

Comment: @Joonas I see that using USB, it's obviously fast. But not with wifi. BTW, I can transfer and play. :)

Comment: I did use VLC player a little, before I decided it was a time for an upgrade. I got myself a Qnap TS-251+ and put Plex server on it. This way I can just transfer files in local network from my pc to the NAS and they show up in the Plex server. You can use it locally and remotely. They have pretty decent mobile apps too. So my Qnap sits at home and I can just connect to it when I wanna watch something. Obviously this is dependent on an internet connection, but for me it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Joonas Okay, I'll try this method. Most of the time, I am connected with Internet.

Comment: @Joonas Please cut the "is it too complicated" attitude.  Transferring files in any kind of normal way from Macbook to iPad is essentially unsupported - thus all these gymnastics. I am a hive/hadoop/java/scala developer and built some pieces of the iTunes IRadio data warehouse at Apple HQ few years back. That does not prevent me from being interested in this question by Mithun - who is dealing with the ridiculous restrictions placed on file transfers by iOS.

Comment: @javadba You may want to quickly take your head off your ass and see the comment for what it is. If you don't provide enough information for me to give an answers, I'm going to either not bother at all ...or try to pry more details so I could possibly give an answer. I'm not trying to point any fingers and say that OP is stupid for not knowing what to do, this is a Q&A site. I'm simply trying to pinpoint where the problem is. Maybe the comment is a bit poorly worded on all accounts, but there is a character limit for comments.

Comment: @javadba  still I'm suffering from this issue. Although, I followed Joonas to transfer, it's not very user friendly.

Comment: @Joonas  actually i'll kind of agree with you here - after re-reading (I *did* go through them before) it does appear that you were honestly trying to help the OP.  Even with limited word count available it makes sense to avoid certain ways of phrasing that appear condescending.

Comment: @javadba Is it not true that a problem that someone can have is that something is too complicated? For example: "I have these parts for an Ikea shelf and these instructions, but this part here is too complicated for me to figure out" You could change it it to say that it's "too hard" or its "too difficult" etc.. but that doesn't really change anything, I don't think.

Comment: @Joonas I do understand your point but you might do some  work on the nuances/tone here.  This is a problem that is far more complicated *than it should be* : it is a weird/(very) questionable artifact of iOS. Therefore answers /suggestions might better focus on *that* angle (i.e. "we have to do more work than anticipated here due to iOS limitations") than "is this too difficult for you". The OP *has* done quite a bit of work as evidenced by his comments/responses to answers and suggestions.

Comment: @javadba I understand that the "PC" culture in your country is way over the top. I'm Finnish, I will be as blunt as I please.

Comment: Congrats on being Finnish: Scandinavia is in general a region in general of great interest to me - though not a traveler.  But I've also met a number of folks from that region  that care at least a bit about how to interact with others. I worked for Nokia and with several researchers in the past: did not mean they had your attitude.

Comment: My politeness will absolutely start decreasing when someone takes something I said out of context and shoves it in my face as a prove of me having some sort of negative attitude towards OP, when it is simply a innocent and totally valid question. Getting back to the actual topic. **@Mithun** I'm curious to know... Your last comment to me implied that you might try Plex. It's been a while since. Did you try it? Did it help? Your last comment to javabda seems to imply you didn't. Why?

Comment: I don't know why this discussion is turning into a wrong direction :( I tried Plex from my friend (borrowed). It's very fine, but at the same time I also feel that this issue might have some good alternative solutions. By the way, I do agree that I'm really stupid, but, I don't feel ashamed to ask help from my friends.

Comment: @Mithun Plex Media Server is very much a mallet solution (depending on the need) to a problem that should only require a hammer. Just.. for what ever reason, the hammers seem to be breaking. If you're willing to connect the device to a computer directly and transfer files through itunes, it isn't half bad. Way more reliable compared to the wi-fi transfer. I would still recommend VLC player. They direct you to the Apple instructions on file trasnfer [here](http://bit.ly/2s7sgXL). I'm afraid that if that isn't enough, then you're just out of luck. I've yet to see a properly working wi-fi share.

Answer (score -1):

You can use some File Manager app. You can AirDrop the entire folder to the Mac, or vice-versa.

Comment: After AirDrop, I could not view the files. Which File Manager do you suggest?

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/file-manager-app/id521405763?mt=8

Comment: Try this one. I use it and it works just fine on my iPhone 7 (iOS 10.1) with a MacBook Pro 2016 (macOS).

Comment: Please edit the link and maybe some details how you use the app directly into the question

Comment: Do I need to install on both Mac and iPad?

Comment: Only on the iPad. The finder is sufficient for the Mac.

Comment: The files when the transfer is complete will be shown in the file manager.